# Why is the location breakdown value different from the search value in Google Keyword Planner

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm new to the AdWords world but I can figure out these different values.

[image]

This is a simple test keyword analysis in the Google Keywords Planner Tool. With all the filters turned off.

Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using "Search for new keywords using a phrase, website or category" planner is showing search volume for all the keywords in all the ad groups that Google's recommending (sum of all suggested keywords)

you need to use "**Get search volume data and trends**" and send only one keyword to get this particular keyword break downs.

[image]